# How to validate HTML through automation using selenium-c# framework?

Tags: c#, selenium

I have tried Validator utility jar from w3c but the those are explicitly java compliant, I have a selenium-c# framework And want to handle html validation programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C#, I suggest you use HTMLAgility Pack.
If you intend to write the business logic yourself, you would have to use a combination of RegEx and XmlReader. You could feel overwhelming.
Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Actually I was looking for any nuget packge or API that I can incorporate in the automation framework, and I have Found one- https://github.com/prokhor-ozornin/W3CValidator.NET but It doesn't contain any information as how to utilize it's functions and all. @sette Thanks for offering the help though, I will explore the pkg in the link if it doesn't work will let you know,